# Installing python with unreachable network due to proxy

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, proxy, installation

I am installing Python 3.7 on a server (Debian Jessie) I have ssh:ed into, and when I run `make test` two of the tests fail with the error `Network unreachable` because the server is behind a proxy. Is there a comfortable way of working around this?

Setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` as environment variables does not work, and searching online for terms like "make proxy" or "python install test" tend to return way to many irrelevant results, so I am not really sure what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
export https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
sudo -E <your command>
```

Using `sudo -E` indicates to the security policy that theyou wnat to use your enviroment variables.

> "-E, --preserve-env"
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
>
> [Sudo Manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.11/sudo.man.html#E)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.